# SKScene отображает разом все Node

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Использую `LevelHelper` + `SpriteKit`. Уровень довольно длинный, порядка 10К пикселей, на нем соответственно куча нодов, `showsNodeCount`показывает 1200+ нодов, но на сколько я понимаю `showsNodeCount` показывает только те ноды, которые сейчас на экране, но на экране и 50 нодов нет - получается вся сцена и все node обрабатываются разом.. есть ли какие то способы проверить это и включить обработку только тех нодов что на экране?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showNodeCound` показывает видимые ноды на сцене и от камеры никак не зависит. У [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcameranode) есть `containedNodeSet()` который ищет все ноды располагающиеся в данный момент на viewport'е камеры и возвращает их набор (set), соответственно можно в printf'е выводить кол-во нод в наборе; и также есть `contains(SKNode)` который говорит, видна ли в данный момент нода во viewport'е камеры или нет.